# PDF document is modified by another revision?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, digital-signature, pdfbox, acrobat

I use PDFbox in order to sign PDF. It works very well. I can add several signature to one document, and everything works well.

Now, someone sign me a document(she sign by another software), this signature was working too. but when I add another revision (by pdfbox) to his document now Adobe reader tells me that PDF was modified.

1. that is original document: [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/030gttevzfz3iof/original.pdf)
2. this is signed document which was done by another software: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fsjvm7gevbqez9w/original-signed%20-%20old.pdf)
3. when I add another revision to the signed pdf, I get this document, which have problems: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/45zw1h8ktuip22m/original-signed-signed%20-old%20new.pdf)
4. If I add another revision to the PDF that was signed by my software, there  is no problem [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mlfr3gpfhl5r1o7/original-signed2-signed.pdf)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## In Short:

Your code applies unnecessary changes to existing PDF objects.

Some changes merely are structural, not changing the actual content. Acrobat Reader might or might not ignore those structural changes. But in the process you introduce rounding errors, and they definitively constitute a change.

The structural changes probably are caused by the quirk of PDFBox to force its preference of which kinds of objects should be direct or indirect onto existing objects it touches.

And the rounding errors while in practice hardly relevant are definitively a no-go when security features are concerned.

When you sign a document twice with PDFBox, the initial signing process already forces PDFBox' preferences into the document and, thus, the second signing process does not destroy anything by again forcing the same preferences into its result.

## The Details:

The original from [original-signed - old.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fsjvm7gevbqez9w/original-signed%20-%20old.pdf):

```
3 0 obj
<<
  /DefaultGray 11 0 R
  /Type/Catalog
  /DefaultRGB 12 0 R
  /AcroForm
  <<
    /Fields[15 0 R]
    /DR<</Font<</Helv 16 0 R/ZaDb 17 0 R>>>>
    /DA(/Helv 0 Tf 0 g )
    /SigFlags 3
  >>
  /Pages 5 0 R>>
endobj 
11 0 obj
[
  /CalGray
  <<
    /WhitePoint [0.9505 1 1.0891 ]
    /Gamma 0.2468
  >>
]
endobj
12 0 obj
[
  /CalRGB
  <<
    /WhitePoint [0.9505 1 1.0891 ]
    /Gamma [0.2468 0.2468 0.2468 ]
    /Matrix [0.4361 0.2225 0.0139 0.3851 0.7169 0.0971 0.1431 0.0606 0.7141 ]
  >>
]
endobj
```

Your re-signed [original-signed-signed -old new.pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/45zw1h8ktuip22m/original-signed-signed%20-old%20new.pdf)

```
3 0 obj
<<
  /DefaultGray [/CalGray 18 0 R]
  /Type /Catalog
  /DefaultRGB [/CalRGB 19 0 R]
  /AcroForm
  <<
    /Fields [15 0 R 20 0 R]
    /DA (/Helv 0 Tf 0 g )
    /SigFlags 3
  >>
  /Pages 5 0 R
>>
endobj
18 0 obj
<<
  /WhitePoint [0.9505000114 1 1.0891000032]
  /Gamma 0.2468000054
>>
endobj
19 0 obj
<<
  /WhitePoint [0.9505000114 1 1.0891000032]
  /Gamma [0.2468000054 0.2468000054 0.2468000054]
  /Matrix [0.4361000061 0.2224999964 0.0138999997 0.3851000071 0.716899991 0.0970999971 0.1430999935 0.0606000014 0.7141000032]
>>
endobj
```

So in essence your code changed indirect arrays (objects 11 and 12) of direct dictionaries into direct arrays (in your new object 3) of indirect dictionaries (your new objects 18 and 19). This is unnecessary and, therefore, there is no need for Adobe Reader to accept it. But it probably would accept this (I don't know, one has to check) if the replacements were identical.

**But they indeed are not identical! Your code introduces rounding errors in these color definitions. And, therefore, it changes the content.**

Additionally your code also introduces structural changes to

```
4 0 obj
<<
  /Parent 5 0 R
  /Contents 9 0 R
  /Type/Page
  /Resources<</ProcSet 2 0 R/Font<</F0 6 0 R/F1 7 0 R>>>>
  /MediaBox[0 0 612 792]
  /Annots[15 0 R]
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
[ /PDF /Text  ]
endobj
```

which you change to

```
4 0 obj
<<
  /Parent 5 0 R
  /Contents 9 0 R
  /Type /Page
  /Resources<</ProcSet [/PDF /Text] /Font 23 0 R >>
  /MediaBox [0 0 612 792]
  /Annots [15 0 R 20 0 R]
>>
endobj 
23 0 obj
<<
  /F0 6 0 R
  /F1 7 0 R
>>
endobj
```

Here you change an indirect array of names into a direct one and a direct dictionary into an indirect one.

Comment: As I understand is this pdfbox bug? I sign document like in the pdfbox examples. what do you think about fixing that issue?

Comment: *I sign document like in the pdfbox examples* - Then it is either a PDFBox core bug or a PDFBox example bug. As mentioned above, PDFBox is quite stubborn about which objects shall be direct and which not, and I indeed do assume that this is the base issue here. You might want to report this as an issue to PDFBox development.

Comment: I open bug in pdfbox jira:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-1778

thank you for your answers :)