# validation digital multi signature PDF

Tags: itext, signature, sign

I need the help of someone who wants to collaborate with the solution of the following problem, I am validating the digital signatures of a PDF with ITEXT, this works very well, the problem that I can not validate the signature is when I have 2 signatures and the first one is invalid , As indicated by Adobe Acrobat, but with the examples of itext consider it as valid, some help please?

Comment: *"the first one is invalid"* - because of which reason? Because of changes in the signed bytes of the first revision or because of disallowed changes in later revisions? Both iText and pdfbox trivially recognize the former while neither checks for the latter.

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, Adobe Reader does *not* complain about a signature becoming invalid because of changes to the signed bytes of the first signed revision but because of additions in the incremental update section to the second signed revision which it considers disallowed.

Neither iText nor PDFBox (which originally also had been mentioned in a tag of the question) check this in their standard signature validation code. Thus, even if the addition in question was disallowed, neither iText nor PDFBox signature validation code would have recognized that.

Actually I don't know whether any PDF product other than Adobe Acrobat / Adobe Reader tries to check whether additions in incremental updates to signed PDFs are disallowed or not.

That being said, even Adobe's tests in this regard are not very good: When they check whether some change is allowed, they often actually check whether the change is executed in a manner Adobe would have executed an allowed change. Thus, if you do some allowed change in a different way, Adobe is likely to claim a disallowed change.

---

This also is the case in the sample document `Con firma fallada.pdf`.

In the first signed revision the PDF **Catalog** object looks like this (pretty printed):

```
1 0 obj
<<
  /Type/Catalog
  /ViewerPreferences 2 0 R
  /Pages 29 0 R
  /AcroForm
  <<
    /DA(/Helv 0 Tf 0 g )
    /Fields[32 0 R]
    /SigFlags 3
    /DR<</Font<</Helv 33 0 R/ZaDb 34 0 R>>>>
  >>
  /Outlines 3 0 R
>>
endobj
```

In the incremental update to the second signed revision an additional signature field has been added, so the object had to be rewritten. The signing software additionally refactored the direct **AcroForm** dictionary object into a new indirect object:

```
1 0 obj
<<
  /Pages 29 0 R
  /AcroForm 35 0 R
  /Type /Catalog
  /ViewerPreferences 2 0 R
  /Outlines 3 0 R
>>
endobj
35 0 obj
<<
  /DA (/Helv 0 Tf 0 g )
  /DR << /Font << /Helv 33 0 R/ZaDb 34 0 R >> >>
  /Fields [ 32 0 R 36 0 R ]
  /SigFlags 3
>>
endobj
```

With this in place, Adobe claims a disallowed change.

If one replaces the above with an equivalent version using a direct **AcroForm** dictionary object, Adobe does not claim that disallowed change anymore:

```
1 0 obj
<<
  /Pages 29 0 R
  /AcroForm
  <<
    /DA (/Helv 0 Tf 0 g )
    /DR << /Font << /Helv 33 0 R/ZaDb 34 0 R >> >>
    /Fields [ 32 0 R 36 0 R ]
    /SigFlags 3
  >>
  /Type /Catalog
  /ViewerPreferences 2 0 R
  /Outlines 3 0 R 
>>
endobj
```

This, by the way, is exactly how the **Catalog** looks like in the incremental update with a second signature in `Con firma buena.pdf`.

(Curiously, though, in that file there also is a copy of the direct **AcroForm** dictionary object in the indirect object 35; probably a sign of someone testing. As that object is not referenced, though, it does not disturb any check...)

Comment: By the way, there is something bad in both `Con firma fallada.pdf` and `Con firma buena.pdf`: They both use the same file identifier ID as the first signed revision. This is against recommendations in the PDF specification.

Comment: Heh heh, stripping the 2nd signature of the fallada file and signing with PDFBox works without Adobe complaining. If PDFBox was used, then it must have been an older version. Because we've had similar problems over a year ago: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3114

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Yes, I also had an old PDFBox issue in my mind (I just found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19905271/1729265)) where PDFBox used to do some changes resulting in an equivalent structure (additionally introducing some rounding errors). Oh, I see your issue refers to that question, too.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that means that no bookstore reaches that level of signature validity, but if you maybe do the Acrobat sdk, or if you have any solution to validate those types of signed files, I would be very grateful.
The program that made the second signature was poorly developed, but now the problem is to recognize all those documents signed with that version of the signature program.
If you have some code, I will thank you very much.
Thank you so much.

Comment: *"if you maybe do the Acrobat sdk"* - I don't. *"or if you have any solution to validate those types of signed files"* - Well, obviously you should not use Adobe products for that because they give wrong results, see above. And as mentioned in my answer, *I don't know whether any PDF product other than Adobe Acrobat / Adobe Reader tries to check whether additions in incremental updates to signed PDFs are disallowed or not.*

Comment: OK, I will continue researching additional libraries to those mentioned, thank you very much your help was very valuable.

Comment: *"the problem is to recognize all those documents"* - you mean *recognize all documents that adobe will complain about*? As long as it's only the difference recognized above (switch from direct to indirect AcroForm object), it would be feasible to implement a test using iText or pdfbox. Can one be sure about that?